# Connection between SAP Hana databases on different servers

Tags: hana

I have a structure of two hana database servers on different servers. I created a trigger on HDB1, which executes a procedure to insert data into another table, but this table is on another HDB2 server.

I'm consulting some possibilities via SDI and SDA, but I'm not sure how to make the connection between the databases, so that the HDB1 procedures can insert data into HDB2.